# Umbraco MemberService GetAll method and return the data to angular js call

Tags: angularjs, umbraco

I am trying to fetch all the member using Memberservice as below

```
 public  GetAllmembers()
{

    int totalRecords;
    var Members = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.GetAll(0, int.MaxValue, out totalRecords);
    foreach (var member in Members)
    {
        //
    }
    return ;

}
```

what could be the best way to store a member and return to the angular js call to display them in a ng-table? any idea on this?

Regards,

Comment: eliminate ajax, use angular $http services

Comment: Hi, sorry i am using angular js call only. i am trying to return the data to that call but confused in returning data in generic list or jobject format.could you suggest the best way and little hint about it?

Comment: update your service function to return json format and pass the list as JSOn

Comment: Like this ' public JsonResult GetAllmembers()
        {
            int totalRecords;
            var Members = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.GetAll(0, int.MaxValue, out totalRecords);
            var viewModel = new List<JsonViewModel>();
            foreach (var member in Members)
            {
                viewModel.Add(new JsonViewModel()
                              {
                                  Name = member.Name
                              });
            }
            return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } '

Comment: or is there is better way?

Comment: First of all, what is your backend implementation? are you using web api?

Comment: I am using ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService service .there are no tables involved in it. GetAll method gets all the member details using the service and returns the data to angular js call.there i am displaying onto ng--table.

Comment: I mean what type of project does GetAllMembers resides? an mvc project? web api? so we can identify how do we connect the angular to your backend

Comment: ohh  got it .its MVC

Comment: i would prefer if you use web api, even if MVC + angular is doable but still webapi is straight forward and sending of request is easy

Comment: ok cool. do you have any example such calls?

Comment: there are many tutorial out there like this http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1049/crud-database-aspnet-webapi-angularjs just take time to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Umbraco therefore use UmbracoWebApi.

Create a controller method that returns your data. In its simplest form, if you want to return all members, you could do this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;

namespace NameOfYourUmbracoWebsiteProject.Controllers.ApiControllers
{
    public class MyMemberController : UmbracoApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<IMember> GetAllmembers()
        {
            var memberService = ApplicationContext.Services.MemberService;
            return memberService.GetAllMembers();
        }

    }
}
```

The endpoint url for this method would be:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/umbraco/api/MyMember/GetAllMembers
```

Create the above method and then test the url in a browser (you will see result as xml rather then JSON).

This would return all of your Members (as JSON if called from angular) ***which is probably not exactly what you want*** therefore you should probably create a Model that contains the properties for each member that you actually need and then return a collection of that.

For example:

```
public class MyCustomMember
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And then change your controller method to return a collection of `MyCustomMember`.  Again if the endpoint is called from angular, web api should return the collection as JSON

```
[HttpGet]
public List<MyCustomMember> GetAllmembers()
{
    var memberService = ApplicationContext.Services.MemberService;

    var listMyCustomMember = new List<MyCustomMember>();

    foreach (var member in memberService.GetAllMembers())
    {
        var myCustomMember = new MyCustomMember
        {
            Name = member.Name,
            Email = member.Email
        };
        listMyCustomMember.Add(myCustomMember);
    }

    return listMyCustomMember;
}
```

Any questions?